# vertically align a label and a textbox in all browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Is there an easy way to align a label with a textbox in all major browsers (i.e. including IE7? I set display to inline-block on my label and textbox which seems to work everywhere but in IE7, where the label is on the bottom of the div.

```
<label class="inputLabel" for="emailTextBox">
            Email:</label>
<input class="textBox" type="text" id="emailTextBox" value=" Email address" />

input.textBox 
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 350px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    line-height: 30px;
    display:inline-block; 
}

label.inputLabel
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Post some code so we can take a look.

Comment: I know it is considered the _dirty_ way but I still use tables for this. It is the only way I've found to reliably handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `display:inline-block` declaration is not [fully supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) by IE7 and below, so you have to use `display:inline` instead in conjunction with the `zoom:1` hasLayout hack to imitate the declaration with the star hack to target IE7. To align both the textbox and labelwe can use the `vertical-align:middle` property, like so:

**CSS**

```
input.textBox {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 350px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    line-height: 30px;
    display:inline-block; 
    *display: inline;     /* for IE7*/
    zoom:1;              /* for IE7*/
    vertical-align:middle;
}

label.inputLabel {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;     /* for IE7*/
    zoom:1;              /* for IE7*/
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9FnxQ/)

Comment: This solution simply creates a taller text box/label, not a centered element. Most of the other solutions around seem to do the same thing. So what about posing the question differently: how would one create a vertically centered _image_?

Comment: "declaration is not fully supported by IE7" in 2012 OK, but for today LOL